# Python line-by-line memory profiler?

Tags: python, memory, profiling

I'm looking to generate, from a large Python codebase, a summary of heap usage or memory allocations over the course of a function's run.

I'm familiar with [heapy](http://guppy-pe.sourceforge.net/), and it's served me well for taking "snapshots" of the heap at particular points in my code, but I've found it difficult to generate a "memory-over-time" summary with it. I've also played with [line_profiler](http://packages.python.org/line_profiler/), but that works with run time, not memory.

My fallback right now is Valgrind with [massif](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html), but that lacks a lot of the contextual Python information that both Heapy and line_profiler give. Is there some sort of combination of the latter two that give a sense of memory usage or heap growth over the execution span of a Python program?

Comment: Could you do it with http://docs.python.org/devguide/gdb.html, if what you care about is happening in the C world?

Comment: A C perspective would be OK, if there were a way to run a gdb automatically at regular intervals - is there such a method?

Comment: A good question, I'm interested to know, so I added a bounty.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would use [`sys.settrace`](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.settrace)  at program startup to register a custom tracer function. The custom_trace_function will be called for each line of code. Then you can use that function to store information gathered by heapy or [meliae](https://launchpad.net/meliae) in a file for later processing.

Here is a very simple example which logs the output of hpy.heap() each second to a plain text file:

```
import sys
import time
import atexit
from guppy import hpy

_last_log_time = time.time()
_logfile = open('logfile.txt', 'w')

def heapy_profile(frame, event, arg):
    currtime = time.time()
    if currtime - _last_log_time < 1:
        return
    _last_log_time = currtime
    code = frame.f_code
    filename = code.co_filename
    lineno = code.co_firstlineno
    idset = hpy().heap()
    logfile.write('%s %s:%s\n%s\n\n' % (currtime, filename, lineno, idset))
    logfile.flush()

atexit.register(_logfile.close)
sys.settrace(heapy_profile)
```

Comment: I haven't tried it *yet*, but it looks like we just might have a winner. (I'll wait until the end of the bounty period to award the points, in case someone else wants to give this question a try)

Answer (score 5):

You might be interested by [memory_profiler](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/).